# Disable/Hide a option with JS or CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to disable/hide a option in select list.
But, this select list not is in my codes, is a pattern of the ecommerce plataform.

And we change the code with a JS, follow:

```
    /*var buttons = "";
$("select option").each(function () {
buttons += "<input type='button' value='" + this.value + "'/>";    
});

$("select").replaceWith(buttons);
*/

var selectName = $('select').attr('name');

// add a hidden element with the same name as the select
var hidden = $('<input type="hidden" name="'+selectName+'">');
hidden.val($('select').val());
hidden.insertAfter($('select'));

$("select option").unwrap().each(function() {
var btn = $('<div class="btn">'+$(this).text()+'</div>');
if($(this).is(':checked')) btn.addClass('on');
$(this).replaceWith(btn);
});
```

HTML + CSS EMBED:

```
<!-- Variações -->
<iluria.if.product.has.variations>
<div class="product-variations-container">
$iluria.product.variations
</div>                              
<script src="variations.js"></script>
<style>
div.btn {display: inline-block;border: 2px solid #ccc;margin-right: 5px;padding: 2px 5px;cursor: pointer;}
div.btn.on {background-color: #777;color: white;}
</style>
</iluria.if.product.has.variations>

    $(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {
    $('.btn').removeClass('on');
    $(this).addClass('on');
    $('input[name="'+selectName+'"]').val($(this).text());
    });
```

Screen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz8NU.jpg

I need to HIDE/DISABLE the option **TAMANHO**

Thank!

Comment: Is the site live? If so, provide a link to the page. I can't replicate just based on that bit of code you provided.

Comment: Sure, sorry.  The link: www.hdmclothing.com.br

Comment: Try and see if this works for you. `.product-variations-container > div:nth-child(4) {
    display: none;
}`

Comment: Work! Great, thank you.

Comment: Great. I'm glad it worked for you.

Comment: for reference: [Browser inspection tools](https://zapier.com/blog/inspect-element-tutorial/)

Comment: Oh sure! Hmm, another question, i dont know if can do it here or need open another question. > This buttons is "Variations" in my stock, and if my stock is "0" for a variation, this show the "size" yet... Its possible put a X (red) inside all variations with stoke "0"? I saw in Inspectin tools the stock values "input quantity"

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to show and hide:

ex: $('input[name="'+selectName+'"]').hide();

```
$('input[name="'+selectName+'"]').show();
```